# Proof related to gcd of three numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

We want to develop a version of the Euclid-Bézout algorithm for triples of natural numbers.

Let $n_1$, $n_2$, $n_3 \in \mathbb{N}$ but not all three zero. We define $\gcd(n_1, n_2, n_3) \in \mathbb{N}$ as the maximum natural number $d$ such that $d\mid n_1$ and $d\mid n_2$ and $d\mid n_3$. For example, $\gcd(70, 105, 770) = 35$, because $35$ is a common divisor and there is no a common divisor which is larger. Let three natural numbers be given (where not all three are $0$ as before, and the order does not matter) We will modify this triple and obtain another triple as follows: Let's call $a_1$ the smallest non-zero number among the three, and let's call $a_2$, $a_3$ the other two numbers. Let $r_2$ be the remainder of $a_2$ after division-with-remainder by $a_1$, and $r_3$ the remainder of $a_3$ after division- with-remainder by $a_1$. Let $b_1:= a_1$, $b_2:= r_2$, $b_3:= r_3$. So from the triple $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$ we get another triple $b_1$, $b_2$, $b_3$. For example the triple $70, 105, 770$ becomes the triple $70, 35, 0$.
I have shown that $\gcd(a_1, a_2, a_3) = \gcd(b_1, b_2, b_3)$ and if $b_2 = b_3 = 0$ then $\gcd(b_1, b_2, b_3) = b_1$.

(i) Let $d = \gcd(a_1, a_2, a_3)$. If $s_1, s_2, s_3$ are three integers such that $s_1b_1 + s_2b_2 + s_3b_3 = d$, find three integers $t_1, t_2, t_3$ such that $t_1a_1 + t_2a_2 + t_3a_3 = d$. For instance, we choose $s_1 = 1$, $s_2 = 0$, $s_3 = 0$ if $b_2 = b_3 = 0$.

Can someone please help me on how to find those three integers?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Use the identity $(a,b,c)=((a,b),c)$ and then use the normal euclidean algorithm (with two inputs) twice.

Comment: It's in your own interest to learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions. Many users in this site won't help you (won't even read your question) if it's not properly formated.

Comment: Proofs and algorithms have been given here many times, e.g. .see the linked dupes (and their links).

Answer (score 0):

$$\gcd(n_1,n_2,n_3)=\gcd(\gcd(n_1,n_2),n_3)$$ $$=\gcd(an_1+bn_2,n_3)$$ $$=\alpha(an_1+bn_2)+\beta n_3$$ $$\alpha an_1+\alpha bn_2+\beta n_3.$$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).